# How can i use $data->id in the checkBoxHtmlOptions yii

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii `cgridview` and i want to add alt in the checkboxes. I am successfull to add this but i want to add `$data->rem_type` i mean variable in this . here is the code i have tried

```
array(
     'name' => 'check',
     'id' => 'selectedIds',
     'value' => '$data->rem_id',
     'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
     'selectableRows' => '100',
     'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array(
      'alt'=>'$data->rem_type'),
),
```

but it producing the html like this

```
<input alt="{$data->rem_type}" value="12" id="selectedIds_0" type="checkbox" name="selectedIds[]">
```

If i removed the quotes (i.e `'alt'=>$data->rem_type)`) it show me the error `Undefined variable: data`

can anybody help me ??

Comment: The data variable is not available in the `checkBoxHtmlOptions` array. for **inspiration** on how to make it available, see this page: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/314/cgridview-use-special-variable-data-in-the-htmloptions-of-a-column-i-e-evaluate-htmloptions-attribute/

Comment: so how can i use variable . I need some attribute in the html produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I haven't tested this but I think you can do it like this:

extend the `CCheckBoxColumn` to `CheckBoxColumn` and overwrite the `getDataCellContent` function:

```
class CheckBoxColumn extends CCheckBoxColumn {

    public function getDataCellContent($row) {
        $data = $this->grid->dataProvider->data[$row];
        if ($this->value !== null)
            $value = $this->evaluateExpression($this->value, array('data' => $data, 'row' => $row));
        elseif ($this->name !== null)
            $value = CHtml::value($data, $this->name);
        else
            $value = $this->grid->dataProvider->keys[$row];

        $checked = false;
        if ($this->checked !== null)
            $checked = $this->evaluateExpression($this->checked, array('data' => $data, 'row' => $row));

        $options = $this->checkBoxHtmlOptions;
        if ($this->disabled !== null)
            $options['disabled'] = $this->evaluateExpression($this->disabled, array('data' => $data, 'row' => $row));

        if (array_key_exists("alt", $options)) { //checks if you have set an alt
            $options['alt'] = $this->evaluateExpression($options['alt'], array('data' => $data, 'row' => $row)); //if you have it will evaluate the expression
        }

        $name = $options['name'];
        unset($options['name']);
        $options['value'] = $value;
        $options['id'] = $this->id . '_' . $row;
        return CHtml::checkBox($name, $checked, $options);
    }

}
```

I have copied most of the code from the original [function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCheckBoxColumn#getDataCellContent-detail)

And added this part:

```
if (array_key_exists("alt", $options)) { //checks if you have set an alt
    $options['alt'] = $this->evaluateExpression($options['alt'], array('data' =>data, 'row' => $row)); //if you have it will evaluate the expression
}
```

There is probably a way to do this better, i.e. not copy the code but I'll let you to this.

Save this in your components folder, include it in your `config.php`.
And use this class in your widget:

```
array(
     'name' => 'check',
     'id' => 'selectedIds',
     'value' => '$data->rem_id',
     'class' => 'CheckBoxColumn',// <-- instead of CCheckBoxColumn
     'selectableRows' => '100',
     'checkBoxHtmlOptions'=>array(
      'alt'=>'$data->rem_type'),
),
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: ohhh yaaa.. sure . i forgot to accept . :p thanks again .it was awesome

Comment: Np, Glad I could help.